# Native file path

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I have started a development of a music player. I made some additional kotlin logic to retrieve all audio files meta data on device from the Android as a list of meta data. I'm trying to understand how a native path should look like for just_audio to understand. My current implementation uses a deprecated key - MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA for contentResolver which returns a path like this /storage/emulated/0/Download/scifri20181123-episode.mp3. Can this path be used by the plugin or I need to find another way to retrieve the path in different format?
The same question is valid for the album art.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if it's a valid file path, then just_audio will be able to open it. You could pass this into `setFilePath`:

```dart
var filePath = '/storage/emulated/....../foo.mp3';
await player.setFilePath(filePath);
```

This is a convenience method for:

```dart
setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.file(filePath)));
```

where `Uri.file(filePath)` will create a `Uri` instance containing something like `file:///storage/emulated/....`. under the hood.

Note that if your app tries to access any file outside of its own app data/cache directories, it also requires permission to do so, and there are [other Flutter packages](https://pub.dev/packages?q=permissions) available to help you with this.

Note also that there is also an existing flutter package using the content resolver API called [flutter_audio_query](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_audio_query), so if it contains what you need, you might not need to write your own Kotlin code.

Comment: When using `setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.file(filePath)))`, can the file path point to assets directly in the flutter directory without extra permissions? I am trying to load local files into a playlist and getting a no such file error

Comment: There is another method called `setAsset(assetPath)` which is a convenience method for `setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('asset:///$assetPath'))`. This accesses the asset directly from the app's AssetBundle and does not require any special permissions.

Comment: I didn't know about that flutter package, I did everything my self :), I can compare what that plugin si doing